# Is there any way to use JIB only for creating a docker image from the given jar?

Tags: spring, docker, gradle, jar, jib

Jib handles all steps of packaging (handles compilation, verification and building the project) your application into a container. However I want to build the jar separately and and provide this jar as a input to JIB to create a docker image and publish to nexus repository.
Is there any way to use JIB only for creating a docker image from the given jar?

Comment: What’s the point? The main power of JIB is that it can layer your application into docker to maximise cache reuse. If you’re just shoving a jar into a container just use a Dockerfile…

Comment: We are already using JIB instead of a docker file in all of the projects. I need the above functionality only in few projects where I obfuscate the application code first, create a jar and then create a docker image out of that jar..

Comment: If you’re just obfuscating code, why do you need to create a jar? Just create the image out of the obfuscated code. Or are you running the obfuscator over your libraries too and packaging a fat jar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to look into the [Jib CLI](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-cli). The jib cli `jar` command is powered by jib-core and lets you build an optimized image from a JAR file. You can find more info on how it works in the [FAQ](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/blob/master/docs/faq.md#how-does-the-jar-command-support-standard-jars) and the [README](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/blob/master/jib-cli/README.md)